# Import JSON file in React with data format error

Tags: json, reactjs

I tried to import a JSON file in my React project, but got the parsing error:

```
json file:testData.json
  {
    "data": {
      "articles": [
            {
            "id": "95c12a8f6c88953ca8f8a39da25546e6",
            "title": "Introducing React's Error Code System",
            "date": "Mon Jul 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
            "authorId": "2c6aa2cfe3449467d329fa17d6ea230f",
            "body": "Building a better developer experience has been one of the things that React deeply cares about, and a crucial part of it is to detect anti-patterns/potential errors early and provide helpful error messages when things (may) go wrong. However, most of these only exist in development mode; in production, we avoid having extra expensive assertions and sending down full error messages in order to reduce the number of bytes sent over the wire."
             }
          ],
       "authors": [
            {
             "id": "d85577ea34ae50f2dac5347b5219aa23",
             "firstName": "Andrew",
             "lastName": "Clark",
             "website": "https://twitter.com/acdlite"
            }
         ]
      }
    }
```

DataApi.js file:

```
export default class DataApi {
// property: rawData
  constructor(rawData) {
   this.rawData = rawData;
 }

   mapIntoObject(arr) {
      return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      acc[curr.id] = curr;
      return acc;
      }, {});
    }
   getArticle() {
      return this.mapIntoObject(this.rawData.articles);
   }
   getAuthors() {
      return this.mapIntoObject(this.rawData.authors);
   }
 }
```

And I tried to import JSON data in this file:

```
import DataApi from "./DataApi"; // object to process data
import { data } from "./testData.json"; // raw data

// create a api object to host raw data
let api = new DataApi(data);

const articles = api.getArticle();

console.log(articles);
```

then I got the error:(the import directory are correct):

```
   2:13  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

  1 | {
> 2 |   "articles": [
    |             ^
  3 |     {
  4 |       "id": "95c12a8f6c88953ca8f8a39da25546e6",
  5 |       "title": "Introducing React's Error Code System",
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can do export default

**testData.json:**

```
const data = {
"data": {
  "articles": [
        {
        "id": "95c12a8f6c88953ca8f8a39da25546e6",
        "title": "Introducing React's Error Code System",
        "date": "Mon Jul 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
        "authorId": "2c6aa2cfe3449467d329fa17d6ea230f",
        "body": "Building a better developer experience has been one of the things that React deeply cares about, and a crucial part of it is to detect anti-patterns/potential errors early and provide helpful error messages when things (may) go wrong. However, most of these only exist in development mode; in production, we avoid having extra expensive assertions and sending down full error messages in order to reduce the number of bytes sent over the wire."
        }
      ],
  "authors": [
        {
        "id": "d85577ea34ae50f2dac5347b5219aa23",
        "firstName": "Andrew",
        "lastName": "Clark",
        "website": "https://twitter.com/acdlite"
        }
    ]
  }
}

export default data;
```

and while importing

With [json-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader) installed, you can use

```
import data from "./testData.json";
```

or If you have used create-react-app to scaffold your project, the module is already included, you just need to import your json:

```
import data from "./testData";
```

To install [json-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader)

```
npm install --save-dev json-loader
```

And add below config to your webpack.config.js

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to export your json data, your json data should be like this.

```
export const data = {
"data": {
  "articles": [
        {
        "id": "95c12a8f6c88953ca8f8a39da25546e6",
        "title": "Introducing React's Error Code System",
        "date": "Mon Jul 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
        "authorId": "2c6aa2cfe3449467d329fa17d6ea230f",
        "body": "Building a better developer experience has been one of the things that React deeply cares about, and a crucial part of it is to detect anti-patterns/potential errors early and provide helpful error messages when things (may) go wrong. However, most of these only exist in development mode; in production, we avoid having extra expensive assertions and sending down full error messages in order to reduce the number of bytes sent over the wire."
        }
      ],
  "authors": [
        {
        "id": "d85577ea34ae50f2dac5347b5219aa23",
        "firstName": "Andrew",
        "lastName": "Clark",
        "website": "https://twitter.com/acdlite"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

change `.json` to `.js` extention,  while importing

```
import { data } from "./testData"; // raw data
```

Comment: I got the data auto copied from online api and stored the data in testData.json file. I just want to import json data directly without change the testData.json. However I tried a few ways and not working. Do you have better ideas? Thanks

Comment: use json loader in that case -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader